# Is there a possibilty to use the @> operator from PostgreSQL in JPA?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jpql

In PostgreSQL, we have the `@>` operator.

It checks if the JSON value exists in a jsonb field.

Is there a possibility to do this in JPQL or is there no other way than a native query?

Comment: Perhaps useful: [JPA and JSON operator native query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901240/jpa-and-json-operator-native-query)

Comment: Since the JPQL syntax is well documented and that is not a valid operator ...